# Knockout array object to modal dialog, passed through submit

Tags: knockout.js

I have a knockout array that populates a table. When I click a row, a modal opens with details of the row displayed.

On submit of modal, I would like to pass the details of the array object with any updates back to the server.

Is there a way to do this without binding the array object ID to another knockout observable?

here is my array:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(type2A, {}, self.circuitsT2A);
```

here is my event that opens the dialog(modal)

```
self.OpenCctView = function (data) {


    console.log(data.PanCctID());
    self.selectbase('400');
    self.modalCctID(data.Assigned());
    self.showDialog(true);
};
```

console.log statement is an int

As can be seen, I pass the array object with data. The object ID is PanCctID.

When I submit the form, I do not know how to call the specific array object in the view modal.

```
self.submit = function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    alert(self.selectbase() );
    self.showDialog(false);
}
```

console.log statement is:

```
basesize: observable()
circuits: observable()
circuitsT2A: observable()
circuitsT2B: observable()
close: ()
getID: (data)
kVA: observable()
modalCctID: observable()
selectbase: observable()
showDialog: observable()
submit: (data)
```

here is my array table binding

```
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr><th>Name</th><th>Cct</th><th>Ph</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: circuitsT2A">
                <tr data-bind="click: $root.OpenCctView">

                    <td data-bind="text: Assigned"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: cct"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Phase"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

modal Code

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-bind="modal:showDialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Circuit Details</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select data-bind="options: basesize,value : selectbase" class="form-control"></select>
                </div

                <div class="form-group">
                    @*<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>*@
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Assignment" data-bind="value: modalCctID">
                </div>

                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Comments" data-bind="text: CctAssigned"></textarea>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click : submit">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click : close">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ViewModel

```
self.circuits = ko.observableArray([]);
self.circuitsT2A = ko.observableArray([]);
self.circuitsT2B = ko.observableArray([]);

//modal details

self.basesize = ko.observableArray(['250', '400', '630', '800']);
self.selectbase = ko.observable();

self.modalCctID = ko.observable();
self.CctAssigned = ko.observable();


//Open Circuit View

self.OpenCctView = function (data) {


    console.log(data.PanCctID());
    self.selectbase('400');
    self.modalCctID(data.Assigned());
    self.showDialog(true);
};


self.showDialog = ko.observable(false);

self.close = function () {

    self.showDialog(false);
}


self.submit = function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    alert(self.selectbase() );
    self.showDialog(false);
}
```

Comment: What is the output of your `console.log` statements?

Comment: I have added it to the question body.

Comment: I get the full array back in circuitsT2A but just want the specific array object.

Comment: Whyt you are showing in your modal, are those all properties of the array element you are displaying?

Comment: share your view as well as complete code .

Comment: No,they are separate properties. I use ko.mapping to pass the elements of the array. These are passed through circuitsT2A. I use modalCctID to store the mapped array object ID in the modal. However, I feel that there must be a way to pass the array object back and forth from the modal without binding the object ID to a new observable.

Comment: on submit `click` you can pass `$data` to click function and do your stuff .

Comment: It's probably better to use the `submit` binding since it passes the form data as a parameter automatically. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html

Comment: I have added more code to the body. Thanks

Comment: If the array element contains observables x,y and z, I can pass them to new observables in the modal. On submit, how would I update the array element with the changes?